# In Kotlin, how to check if the input is alphabetic only

Tags: kotlin, inout, alphabetic

In kotlin, how to check if the input is alphabetic only.
Input could be anything, a `String`, `Int` or `Double` etc.

For example

```kotlin
val input = readLine()
if(check) {
   doSomeTask
}
else doSomethingElse
```

Comment: Also depending on your requirements, you can always do `"someString".isDigitsOnly().not()` but that won't exclude a string that contains digits obviously.

Comment: Check my edit. Convert input to string with `toString()` . It handles null and will format a number correctly.

Comment: Does *alphabetic only* include or exclude punctuation and hyphons etc.?

Comment: Only alphabets...

Answer (score 7):

You can have a look [here](https://www.techiedelight.com/check-if-string-contains-only-alphabets-kotlin/), there are a lot of examples.

for example you can check via

```
fun isLetters(string: String): Boolean {
    return string.all { it.isLetter() }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I too found all{it.isLetter} function to be easy and readable

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex with the alphabet range:

```
fun alphabetCheck(input: String): Boolean {
    val regex = Regex("[a-zA-Z]+?")
    return regex.matches(input)
}
```

First convert your input to string by using `toString()`:

```
val str = input.toString()
val matchesAlphabet = alphabetCheck(str)
```

Comment: This isn't working, whatever the input is given, the check is moving to else statement.

Comment: @AbhiAbhishek sorry I was missing the +? at the end of the Regex pattern. Now it should work I tried in the kotlin playground. This ensures it matches all the input and not just the first character.

Comment: You can add more things like punctuation and spaces to the regex expression `[a-zA-Z\\s\\.]+?`

Answer (score 2):

A good answer for checking if a `String` is entirely alphabetical was given by @HakobHakobyan: `String.all { it.isLetter() }`.

I will *borrow* his solution to target a second aspect of your question, that is

> *Input could be anything, a string, int or double etc.*

Here's another method that checks `Any` input type:

```kotlin
fun isAplhabetical(input: Any): Boolean {
    when (input) {
        // if the input is a String, check all the Chars of it
        is String -> return input.all { it.isLetter() }
        // if input is a Char, just check that single Char
        is Char -> return input.isLetter()
        // otherwise, input doesn't contain any Char
        else -> return false
    }
}
```

and it can be used in an example `main()` like this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val a = "Some non-numerical input"
    val b = "45"
    val c = "Some numbers, like 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on"
    val d: Int = 42
    val e: Double = 42.42
    val f: Float = 43.4333f
    val g = "This appears as entirely alphabetical" // but contains whitespaces
    val h = "ThisIsEntirelyAlphabetical"
    
    println("[$a] is" + (if (isAplhabetical(a)) "" else " not") + " (entirely) alphabetical")
    println("[$b] is" + (if (isAplhabetical(b)) "" else " not") + " (entirely) alphabetical")
    println("[$c] is" + (if (isAplhabetical(c)) "" else " not") + " (entirely) alphabetical")
    println("[$d] is" + (if (isAplhabetical(d)) "" else " not") + " (entirely) alphabetical")
    println("[$e] is" + (if (isAplhabetical(e)) "" else " not") + " (entirely) alphabetical")
    println("[$f] is" + (if (isAplhabetical(f)) "" else " not") + " (entirely) alphabetical")
    println("[$g] is" + (if (isAplhabetical(g)) "" else " not") + " (entirely) alphabetical")
    println("[$h] is" + (if (isAplhabetical(h)) "" else " not") + " (entirely) alphabetical")
}
```

The output is

```
[Some non-numerical input] is not (entirely) alphabetical
[45] is not (entirely) alphabetical
[Some numbers, like 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on] is not (entirely) alphabetical
[42] is not (entirely) alphabetical
[42.42] is not (entirely) alphabetical
[43.4333] is not (entirely) alphabetical
[This appears as entirely alphabetical] is not (entirely) alphabetical
[ThisIsEntirelyAlphabetical] is (entirely) alphabetical
```

Only the last `String` is entirely alphabetical.

Comment: Hmm... why is `String` not highlighted in the code? Is that a fail of mine or one of the new syntax highlighting?

Comment: Looks fine on their mobile app, which hasn’t been updated in years.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the ascii value of a character as in the example:

```
fun main(args: Array) {

    val c = 'a'
    val ascii = c.toInt()

    println("The ASCII value of $c is: $ascii")
}
```

If you look at the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/), you can see that alphabetic characters are the one between the values 65 and 90 for capital letters. For small letters you have the interval 97 - 122.

Comment: *) for very limited alphabets.

Comment: you have the extended ascii too

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build an arbitrary lookup (say characters that fit an encoding like base 64) you can do this kind of thing too:

```
val acceptable = ('a'..'z').plus('A'..'Z').plus("+-/~".asIterable())
```

So that's using ranges as a quick way of defining a... range of characters, and using a string to easily specify some individual ones (and turning it into an `Iterable<Char>` so `plus` can add them to the list.

```
val Char.isAcceptable get() = this in acceptable

"ab+5%".filter(Char::isAcceptable).let { print("VIPs: $it")}
>>>> VIPs: ab+
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follows:

```
fun checkDigitOrLetter(c: Char) = when (c) {
   in '0'..'9' -> "Digit!"
   in 'a'..'z', in 'A'..'Z' -> "Letter!" 
   else -> "None"
}
```